# Extract multiple strings between two words in a file

Tags: batch, text-editing, c++

I have a text file made this way:

```
hjkhkhkjhkh<start:"xxxxxxxxxxxx:"alt>asdsadasd<start:"yyyyyyyyyyyyyy:"alt>gfhfg
hujhyfgh<start:"zzzzzzz:"alt>...........<start:"ttttttttttt:"alt>kjlhkjkgugilkl
```

I have to create N files isolating the chars between `<start:"` and `:"alt>`

- file_1.txt ----> xxxxxxxxxxxx
- file_2.txt ----> yyyyyyyyyyyyyy
- file_3.txt ----> zzzzzz
- ....
- ....
- file_N.txt ----> ttttttttttttt

Every group (xxxxx, yyyyy, ....., tttt) is a casual sequence of thousands of chars in the base64-like alphabet `[a-z A-Z 0-9 +/=]`

I'm looking for a C++ or Batch code that can do this work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The hint is "regex" or "regular expression"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple using [JREPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs regular expression search and replace on text](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). JREPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

**Solution 1 doing some of the work with JREPL and some with batch:**

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (
  'jrepl "<start:\q(.*?):\qalt>" $1 /x /jmatch /f test.txt'
) do (
  set /a n+=1
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  >file_!n!.txt echo(!ln!
  endlocal
)
```

**Solution 2 doing all the work with JREPL using a batch variable for JScript code:**

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Define beg variable to hold JScript code
:: It is actually one line with line continuation to make it easier to read.
set beg=^
var n=0;^
function write(txt){^
  var fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');^
  var out=fso.OpenTextFile('file_'+(++n)+'.txt',2,true);^
  out.WriteLine(txt);^
  out.close();^
  return false;^
}

call jrepl "<start:\q(.*?):\qalt>" "write($1)" /x /jmatch /jbeg="%beg%" /f test.txt
```

**Solution 3 doing all work with JREPL using an external file containing JSCRIPT code:**

file named write.jrepl

```
var n=0;
function write(txt){
  var fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
  var out=fso.OpenTextFile('file_'+(++n)+'.txt',2,true);
  out.WriteLine(txt);
  out.close();
  return false;
}
```

command line (no batch needed)

```
jrepl "<start:\q(.*?):\qalt>" "write($1)" /x /jmatch /jlib=write.jrepl /f test.txt
```

====================================================

**Update to eliminate unwanted newlines**

The following is Solution 1 modified to first eliminate the carriage returns and newlines. This can be adapted to solutions 2 and 3.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (
  'jrepl "[\r\n]" "" /m /f test.log^|jrepl "<start:\q(.*?):\qalt>" $1 /x /jmatch'
) do (
  set /a n+=1
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  >file_!n!.txt echo(!ln!
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: I tried the Solution 1 but the program seems to work differently almost every time I run it. It's very stange. I'm trying to understand this problem. Thank you

Comment: @user3133076 - That is just weird. It works consistently for me using the data you provided.

Comment: The problem: If the program works right, I change a char in test.txt, the program doesn't work right, I re-change that char to the original value and the program keeps not working even if now the file is identical to the start. I don't know what to think. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I understood the problem, but I need help to solve it. The strange behavior of the program is caused by an unidentified "space\return carriage" char after every `<start:"` occurrence in the original input file. This causes the special char to be wrongly recognized as part of the string to save, so the program doesn't work correctly. Please check my .txt input file (300 byte) [link](http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=1005515) Any ideas? Thank you very much for your time. –

Comment: I solved the problem by pre-deleting all the return-carriage chars from my files with Notepad++. Thank you

Comment: @user3133076 - No need to manually do that. I've added a modified Solution 1 to do that programmatically