# Batch file to edit text in a file to a new file

Tags: batch, script, batch-file

I have a text file **Old.txt** with the below contents:

```
hierarchies
dimensions
products
product 11
product 12
scenario
scenario budget
actual
PerformanceUnit
PU1
PU3
PU46
PU23
PU2
PU245
NoPerformanceUnit
Noscenario
Noproduct
Noheirachies
```

I need a batch script to save everything in between `PerformanceUnit` to `NoPerformanceUnit` in another text file called **New.txt**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a task for a Windows implementation of `awk`, or for PowerShell. You can find `awk` in the CygWin tools, in the Windows Subsystem for Linux once you've downloaded and activated a distro, or from several locations on the web ([search for **awk for windows command line**](https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+for+windows+command+line)).

Comment: We don't write scripts if you show no effort of atleast trying. We're not a batch script service. Please do some research and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1425633/edit) your question to show what have you already tried

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - You don't need something as elaborate as `awk` or `sed` for this simple case: instead, `for /f "delims=" %%L in (FileName) do ...` will allow you to check each line in `%%L` and write it or not as the boundary lines are encountered. See [`for /f``](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract multiple strings between two words in a file](https://superuser.com/questions/850183/extract-multiple-strings-between-two-words-in-a-file)